# How to use FastAPI's lifespan to manage connection pool creation and relase?

Tags: python, fastapi

I want to use FastAPIs `lifespan` to create redis connection pool.

Currently my implementation looks like that:

1. My APIs has the following dependencies

```py
@router.post("/items")
async def post_items(r: RedisDependency): ...
```

2. `RedisDependency` is:

```py
RedisDependency = Annotated[Redis, Depends(get_redis)]
```

3. `get_redis` function is:

```py
import redis.asyncio as aredis

from . import pool


async def get_redis() -> aredis.Redis:
    r = aredis.Redis(connection_pool=pool, decode_responses=True)
    try:
        yield r
    finally:
        await r.aclose()
```

4. The pool is imported into mine redis module from `db/__init__` file, where it initialized:

```py
import redis.asyncio as aredis

from app.core.config import settings

def create_redis_pool():
    return aredis.ConnectionPool.from_url(settings.REDIS_URL)

pool = create_redis_pool()
```

With current implementation the pool is created outside FastAPIs lifespan. I've seen examples, where people use something like this:

```py
@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    app.state.r = await init_redis()
    yield
    await app.state.r.aclose()
```

and then uses it via:

```py
@router.post("/items")
async def post_items(req: Request):
    redis = req.app.state.r
    ...
```

which beats the purpose the convenience of `Depends(get_resourse)`.

So the question is, is there more optimal way to use `lifespan`s and not involve weird `request.app.state.resourse` usage in API?

Answer (score 1):

FastAPI's on_event system can be used to manage connection pool creation and release during the lifespan of the FastAPI application. Specifically, you can use the startup and shutdown events to handle the creation and release of resources such as database connection pools.

Here's a basic example of how you might use FastAPI's on_event system to manage a connection pool using a library like asyncpg (an asynchronous PostgreSQL library). This example assumes you have already installed fastapi and asyncpg:

```py
app = FastAPI()
# Configuration settings
database_url = "postgresql://user:password@localhost/dbname"

async def get_database():
    pool = await asyncpg.create_pool(database_url)
    yield pool
    pool.close()
    await pool.wait_closed()

async def get_db_connection(database: asyncpg.pool.Pool = Depends(get_database)):
    async with database.acquire() as connection:
        yield connection

@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event():
    app.db_pool = await asyncpg.create_pool(database_url)

@app.on_event("shutdown")
async def shutdown_event():
    await app.db_pool.close()

# Example route using the database connection pool
@app.get("/items/{item_id}")
async def read_item(item_id: int, db: asyncpg.connection.Connection = Depends(get_db_connection)):
    # Use the database connection to fetch data, perform operations, etc.
    # ...
    return {"item_id": item_id}
```

Comment: 1.The get_database dependency is responsible for creating and managing the database connection pool. It yields the pool for use in other dependencies and routes.

Comment: 2. The get_db_connection dependency is responsible for getting a database connection from the pool. It yields the connection for use in the route.   
3.The startup_event and shutdown_event functions use FastAPI's on_event system to create and close the database connection pool, respectively.
4.The read_item route uses the get_db_connection dependency to get a database connection from the pool and use it within the route.

Comment: `on_event` decorators are [deprecated](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/#alternative-events-deprecated)